# How to use anonymous functions in PHP5.3

Tags: php, anonymous-function

I recently really wanted to us [anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) in PHP. Unfortunately my host is still on `5.2`. I automatically *thought* this would work:

```
uasort($array, function($a, $b) {
    return $a > $b;
});
```

Is this how they work? Simply passed in as an argument instead of a callback? The docs don't say specifically that's how they do, but I have a working knowledge of JavaScript's anonymous functions, so I assumed they would.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can use it in place of regular PHP callbacks.

Try this (in PHP 5.3):

```
function wait($callback)
{
    sleep(10);
    call_user_func($callback);
}

wait(function(){
    echo "Hello!";
});
```

How `call_user_func()` works is it will accept any of the following:

```
'functionName'
array('className', 'methodName')
array($objectInstance, 'methodName');
```

and now in PHP 5.3

```
function(){ // .. do something .. 
}
```

My guess is that internal PHP functions user `call_user_func()` for callbacks, and because it has support for anonymous functions, they will work just as well as other callbacks.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just wondering, what are the practical uses of `sleep()`?

Comment: If you want to limit how many things happen per set time. In example, Twitter only provides 150 calls per hour. I might `sleep()` between calls in a loop to make sure I don't hit 150 calls in an hour.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I've just always used server side caching for things like that.

Comment: I mean in a cronjob, when a script is running continuously. Like I am searching for my name and adding the data to a database. I can have script always running, and limit the calls.

Comment: I just read the docs from the beginning and it *does* say you can use them as callbacks. Whoops.